# RemoveError on updating packages in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, updates, conda

I want to update my packages for which I ran the command

```
conda update --all
```

but it is giving the error

> "RemoveError: This operation will remove conda without replacing it
>   with another version of conda."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right, this is the correct command.

```
conda update --all
```

but what happens is that some packages are dependent on other packages. Say, the X package requires Y <=3.0, so Y will never upgrade to the newer version if available.

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972052/anaconda-update-all-possible-packages) in detail.

I recommend updating individual packages as per requirement.

Hope it helps.
Peace out.