# Can't Update Python in Anaconda Base Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment, radix

In Windows10 I am not able to update Python from current version 3.8.1 to 3.10 in Anaconda 'Base' environment.

Other environments, except Base were successfully updated to 3.10.10

Nothing contained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70820752/how-to-update-python-in-anaconda-base-environment) thread worked.

If it matters Anaconda Navigator doesn't launch due to QT error.