# Can pip be used to upgrade package installed with conda forge?

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda, upgrade

A package was installed through conda-forge

```
conda install -c conda-forge <package>
```

However, I don't know how to upgrade the package to the newest version, because

```
conda install --upgrade -c conda-forge openai
```

didn't work, so I typed

```
pip install --upgrade <package>
```

Somehow it worked, but does it affect the package dependency?

Comment: Try `conda update -c conda-forge openai` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44072944/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+upgrade

Comment: The premise here is basically a typo (it's `conda upgrade`). But sure, `pip` *can* be used, but Conda defaults to not recognize it as satisfying dependencies because...[it's complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75467411/570918).

Comment: @phd Thank you, it worked. In general, if there's no dependence issues, then conda install and pip install worked the same is it? they both install the packages in the anaconda3 folder.

Comment: Conda and `pip` are [two completely different beasts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20994716/7976758). Once you've started to use `conda` the advice is to use it for everything except when a package is not available; for such a case temporary return to `pip`.